# Pi-system and the union of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, let $\mathcal{G}_1, \mathcal{G}_2, \ldots \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be $\sigma$-algebras and let $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(\mathcal{G}_1 \cup \mathcal{G}_2 \cup \ldots)$.

Now, I want to show that 
\begin{align}
\Pi = \{ G_{i_1} \cap G_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap G_{i_k}: k \in \mathbb{N}, i_k \in \mathbb{N}, G_{i_j} \in \mathcal{G}_{i_j}\}
\end{align} 
is a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal{G}$.

First, take $E,F \in \Pi$, then
\begin{align}
E &= G_{i_1} \cap G_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap G_{i_k}\ \text{ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and}\\
F &= G_{j_1} \cap G_{j_2} \cap \ldots \cap G_{j_l}\ \text{ for $l \in \mathbb{N}$}.
\end{align}
Now, why is it true that 
\begin{align}
(*) \qquad E \cap F = (G_{i_1} \cap G_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap G_{i_k}) \cap (G_{j_1} \cap G_{j_2} \cap \ldots \cap G_{j_l})
\end{align}
is in $\Pi$? (since $k$ does not have to be equal to $l$ we can not evaluate $(*)$ pairwise)

Second, since $G_{i_j} \in \mathcal{G}_{i_j}$ and since the $\mathcal{G}_{i_j}$'s are $\sigma$-algebras, it follows that 
\begin{align}
&G_{i_1} \cap G_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap G_{i_k} \in \sigma(\mathcal{G}_1 \cup \mathcal{G}_2 \cup \ldots)=\mathcal{G}\ \text{ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$}.\\
&\implies \sigma(\Pi) \subseteq \mathcal{G}.
\end{align}
How to prove that the other inclusion hold as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point, it may be simpler to notice that 
$\Pi=\left\{G_1\cap\dots\cap G_N,G_i\in\mathcal G_i, 1\leqslant i\leqslant N\right\}$. This because $\Omega$ belongs to $\mathcal G_i$ for any $i$ so we can choose $G_i=\Omega$ if $i$ is not of the form $i_k$. 
In this way, if $G'=\bigcap_{i=1}^m  G'_i$ and $G''=\bigcap_{j=1}^n  G''_j$ with $G_i\in\mathcal G_i$ and $G_j\in\mathcal G_j$ for any $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $j\in \{1\dots,n\}$ where $m\geqslant n$, then $G'\cap G''=\bigcap_{i=1} ^{m}G'_i\cap G''_i$ where we define $G'_i=\Omega$ if $n+1\leqslant i\leqslant m$.

For the second part, notice that $\mathcal G_i\subset\Pi$ for any $i$ (we choose $N=i$ and $G_l=\Omega$ for $1\leqslant l\lt i$) hence $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N^*}\mathcal G_i\subset\Pi$